# Finding an element in array of ObjectId in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a list of ObjectId's mapped using Morphia. In java, the mapping looks like this:

```
public class Log {
    @Indexed
    public List<ObjectId> companyIds;
    ....
}
```

In Mongo shell, however, when I search using $elemMatch it will complain about invalid type.

```
> db.Log.find({ "companyIds" : { "$elemMatch" : ObjectId("5059e90d0364d02be740417a")}})
error: {
    "$err" : "invalid parameter: expected an object ($elemMatch)",
    "code" : 10065
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do to use $elemMatch with ObjectId's?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use `$elemMatch` to do this.  You can just run the query

```
{ "companyIds" : ObjectId("...") }
```

which will find all objects whose companyIds field contains the given objectId.

According to the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$elemMatch), `$elemMatch` is only necessary when you're trying to match against multiple fields on an array element.  The reason it's saying "expected an object" is that `$elemMatch` takes a full fledged mongo query (as in, something that you could pass to `find`) as it's argument.